# Magento 2 : How to Display Product Id on Product View Page

Tags: magento2, product, frontend

I want to display product id on product view page when user click on product.

For ex :- This product id is 1. When This page is display on this page I want to display product id 1.

How can I get ?

Please help me.....

[image]

Comment: which position, you want to display product id.

Comment: which product user view...that product's id want to display on that product view page....

Comment: want to display in alert box..when page load...

Comment: You can use `$_product->getId()` on phtml where you want product id. ofcourse related to product detail page.

Comment: can you give me answer with code? @Kul

Answer (score 5):

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');

$currentProduct = $registry->registry('current_product');

echo $currentProduct->getId();
```

You can get current product id using this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code on template file from here . Please use your theme and if you dont have files here copy from vendor.

```
app/design/frontend/package/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/
```

Packag and theme should be change as per your theme
Add below code to get product id

```
<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>
```